# Can all gifts contain Eggs?

Tags: pokemon-go

If there is no free space in the Egg inventory, it's impossible to obtain an Alola Egg. Is this checked when the Gift is received whether you open it or not (much like the eggs), or it is checked at the moment you try to open it?

Comment: If you want to receive Alola eggs you need to have a spot free and it will be interesting to know if it makes sense to wait to open your received gifts or not

Comment: I have a feeling the gifts are not predetermined and function like a mini-pokestop, but it will require more testing to be sure. I was able to open gifts while having a full egg inventory. If the gifts were predetermined and it had an egg, it more than likely would have outputted a full inventory in the same manner as a pokestop

Comment: Other than for eggs, it is impossible to know.

Comment: One way to check would have been keeping many Gifts from the time before Stardust was a possible reward and then opening them all and checking for Stardust. Did anyone do that or keep very old Gifts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You can always obtain an egg**.

I tested this myself with multiple gifts. I followed some gifts I received when I had no egg space, and when I finally had a free spot I opened them and received a 7km egg.

Comment: This doesn't really prove anything, though. I've often received Gifts with only 1 or 2 items, it's very possible that contents are determined when the Gift is sent, and if there is no Egg space when it's opened, the Egg is simply lost.

Comment: The important idea here is that no matter when you received the gift. If you free egg space you can open any gift and be able to receive an egg

Comment: While that's true and certainly important, that wasn't the question. Since it's the only really relevant part, I suppose it makes more sense to change the question accordingly, but as it is now, the answer doesn't fit the question.

Comment: Feel free to reword the question to be more accurate

Comment: You can't prove that the content, other than for the egg, is decided in the moment of opening. If you receive a gift containing Great balls, it is impossible to know whether they were there at the moment when the gift was sent or randomly generated at the moment of opening the gift.

Comment: @SysDragon Typically speaking, provided the question is within Arqade's guidelines such as being clear, it's the answers that are editted to be more accurate in answering the question, instead of rewording the question to suit the answer. I think you know what the answer is, but "you can always obtain an egg" doesn't clearly answer your question of "is the gift checked when received or opened."

Comment: @MBorg Disagree

Comment: Rereading this, your title question is "Can all gifts contain eggs", which your answer does answer. Your question OP is "is the gift checked when received or opened," which is actually a duplicate question from the linked answer in my answer

Answer (score 3):

It is checked the moment you try to open the gift, not when you receive the gift. If you have free space when you open the gift, you have a chance to receive an Alolan egg. Note the word chance: it is not guaranteed you'd get an egg even if you open a gift with free space.

[As per this question and answer,](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/338552/are-eggs-from-gift-predetermined-before-you-open-the-gift) there are cases of Pokemon receiving Pokemon from eggs that were available when the eggs were open, but not when the gifts were received.

Comment: As said by @scenia: "This doesn't really prove anything, though. I've often received Gifts with only 1 or 2 items, it's very possible that contents are determined when the Gift is sent, and if there is no Egg space when it's opened, the Egg is simply lost."

Comment: @SysDragon Thanks for the feedback. I found some evidence from a previous question in which Alolan Geodudes were received from egg gifts, where the gifts were received before Geodude was available