# Are eggs from gift predetermined before you open the gift?

Tags: pokemon-go

In Pokemon-Go are eggs from gifts predetermined before you open the gift?

Looking for the ultra bonus of September 2018 with Kanto regional pokemon on 7KM eggs I want to save egg space hatching current ones and not taking more, and also I am not opening gift from friends until the event.

If I open the gift (and give me eggs) on september 13th will be determined the pokemon using the event at the moment? Or are they determined the day the gift is sent?

Comment: When Geodude entered the Alolan eggs it is possible that people payed attention on this thing. The situation is essentially the same, but no one was this interested about getting Alolan Geodude.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

I received gifts from 5 friends september 10th 2018 (before de event). I didn't accept gifts or received eggs from Pokestops for several days.

The september 13th 2018 opened the 5 gifts getting 5 eggs of 7 km. After hatching them they were:

- 2 Alolan Diglett
- 1 Alolan Sandshrew
- 1 Mr. Mime
- 1 Tangela

Answer (score 3):

The Egg is determined when you receive it. Many people have received regional Pokemon that were only available during a specific time window from opening gifts within the event time, even though those gifts were received before the event time.

Comment: I don't think it's so clear-cut: there's 4 extra steps with gifts. They can be received from a Pokestop (step 1), sent to someone (step 2), received (step 3) and opened (step 4). as such I don't think it's enough to say *'when the egg is received'*. A more definitive proof would be to check the geographic origin of the hatchling; whether it's from where you 'received' it, or the original gift Pokestop's location. (as a hatchling's location is [determined when the egg is found](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/286369/28182))

Comment: @Robotnik The geographic origin of the Pokemon from a gift egg is the original Pokestop the gift was sent from. My Alolan Pokemon range from Japan, Scotland, Germany, and various states in the US. But agreed, there is still more to it than just *when the egg is received*

Comment: The gift's location is saved anyway, transferring it to the egg when the gift is opened and an egg is rolled produces no programmatic or data overhead. Determining what an egg contains before there's even reason to assume an egg will ever exist (such as when receiving a gift from a stop or from a friend) *does* produce significant programmatic and data overhead. Pokestops are probably referenced internally by ID, so saving egg content additionally makes the data objects for gift at least twice as large when it's much simpler to just reuse the code for receiving eggs from stops.